# CSS and JS files not loading in Production mode

Tags: magento-2.1, developer-mode, production-mode

I am changing my site to Production mode but CSS,JS is not loading after changing to production mode.

Group product has very odd issue. Display in Developer mode but not in Production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

CSS and JS may not be loading due to following reasons

1. Due to old cache. Clear cache. You can clear cache from System -> Cache management or from Mage_Root_Folder/var/cache
2. Incorrect file permission/ownership of files/folders. For correct permission visit

   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html